# GoIbibo Automation Scenario

Tags: selenium

Trying to automate Goibibo Hotel Search, but after clicking on Search Button, it goes to the Results page, but not loading complete page. It is not displaying the hotel options and other options on page. It is showing like processing to load. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: It uses Ajax dynamic loading. `x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='infinite-scroll-component ']")  print(x.text)`. This gives all the hotel text to an extent (until the first load). If you want to keep loading the data, you may have to scroll until the last element, so that the webpage updates with the new content and then resume the extraction operation. A little tricky, I believe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.